# function not return value from request

Tags: javascript, reactjs, ajax, axios, request

I made a function to get request. It look like this

```
export const toggleCompleted  = (id) => {
    axiosMethod.get('api/taks/toggle/' + id)
               .then(res => {
                   console.log(res.data)
                  return res.data;
               }).catch(error => {
                   return error;
               })
    return 'Test';
}
```

I want to get this request and if PHP return true, run dispatch. So I made this code

```
const markAsCompleted = (id) => {
    console.log(toggleCompleted(id));
    if (toggleCompleted(id) == 1){
        toggleMarkAsCompleted(id);
    }
   

}
```

**toggleCompleted** is a my request which is show before
**toggleMarkAsCompleted**is my dispatch.
If toggleCompleted return 1 I want to run my dispatch. It's simple? Interested is that this code

```
console.log(toggleCompleted(id));
```

return Test while my request 1 or 0 (from .then()). Why?

Comment: `toggleCompleted` doesn't `return` anything

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to return the response from an asynchronous call](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14220321/how-to-return-the-response-from-an-asynchronous-call)

Answer (score 0):

Add return in the `toggleCompleted` and use `async/await` to get return data

```
export const toggleCompleted = (id) => {
  return axiosMethod
    .get("api/taks/toggle/" + id)
    .then((res) => {
      console.log(res.data);
      return res.data;
    })
    .catch((error) => {
      return error;
    });
};

const markAsCompleted = async (id) => {
  const res = await toggleCompleted(id);
  if (res == 1) {
    toggleMarkAsCompleted(id);
  }
};
```